# htaccess - all rewrites are being 302 redirected

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

The relevant parts of the htaccess file are:

```
Options +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch -MultiViews
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^/?services/([^\.]+)/?$ http://www.domain.com/somefolder/web_services/instructions.php?service=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Visiting a relevant page directly also causes a URL redirect. Ive tried removing all the other rules to check for a double redirect and that did not change anything.

Anybody know what would cause EVERY rewrite to be a 302 redirect?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to remove `http://` from target URI to avoid full redirect:

```
Options +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch -MultiViews
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^/?services/([^.]+)/?$ somefolder/web_services/instructions.php?service=$1 [L,QSA,NC]
```

Comment: Lol thought it might have somethign to do with this but couldnt think of any reason it would :P  Many many thankyous sir!